# Slice keywords from log text files

Tags: bash, shell, text, text-processing

I have a big log file with lines as

```
[2016-06-03T10:03:12] No data: TW.WA2
```

,

```
[2016-06-03T11:03:02] wrong overlaps: XW.W12.HHZ.2007.289
```

and as

```
[2016-06-03T14:05:26] failed to correct YP.CT02.HHZ.2012.334 because No matching response.
```

Each line consists of a timestamp, a reason for the logging and a keyword composed of some substrings connected by dots (`TW.WA2`, `XW.W12.HHZ.2007.289` and `YP.CT02.HHZ.2012.334` in above examples).

The format of the keywords of a specific type is fixed (substrings are joined by fixed number of dots).

The substrings are composed of letters and digits (0-5 chars, but not all substrings can be empty, generally only one at maximum, e.g., `XW.WTA12..2007.289`).

I want to

- extract the keywords
- save different types of keywords uniqued to separated files

Currently I tried `grep`, but only the classification is done.

- `grep "wrong overlaps" logfile > wrong_overlaps`
- `grep "failed to correct" logfile > no_resp`
- `grep "No data" logfile > no_data`

In `no_data`, the contents are expected as like

```
AW.AA1
TW.WA2
TW.WA3
 ...
```

In `no_resp`, the contents are expected as like

```
XP..HHZ.2002.334
YP.CT01.HHZ.2012.330
YP.CT02.HHZ.2012.334
 ...
```

However, the simple `grep` commands above save the full lines. I guess I need regex to extract the keywords?

Comment: How exactly do you differentiate the pattern. Consider the  posting more sample input and output..

Comment: @shellter  I don't have a lot of idea on how to extract. I didn't mean to ask for a completed code, but suggestions on how to make it. For example, what is the best command to accomplish it with easy?

Comment: OK, good update, But before I revoke my close vote, please also update your Q with expected output. Actual sample output rather than Verbal descriptions eliminate a whole class of errors for specifying fixes. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter  Display inputs and outputs straightforward and show my past tries in the Q! OK, I'll keep in mind afterwards.

Comment: While I respect and use complex reg-exp (and upvote those answers;-). I think your what you have shown us, a simpler approach may be ok. For your first set of data, why not just `sed -n '/^*No data:/s/^.*No data://p' logFile`. Similar constructs are possible for all of your samples, and in 3rd case, can be chained together like `sed -n '/^.*failed to correct/{s/^.*failed to correct//;s/ because No matching response\.$//' logFile` If you wanteto get crazy, use the `w file` option to filter to indiv. files. And for the sed obsessed, you can further reduce to sed -n '/^*No data:/s///p' logFile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a keyword is defined by containing period and surrounded by letters and digits, then the followed regex will match all keywords:

```
% grep -oE '\w+(\.\w+)+' data
TW.WA2
XW.W12.HHZ.2007.289
YP.CT02.HHZ.2012.334
```

`-o` will print the matches only. And `-E` enables Extended Regular Expressions

This will however not make it possible for you to split it into multiply files, eg: Creating a file `wrong_overlaps` that contains all lines with `wrong overlaps`.

You can use `-P` to enable Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which support lookbehinds:

```
% grep -oP '(?<=wrong overlaps: )\w+(\.\w+)+' data
XW.W12.HHZ.2007.289
```

But note that PCRE doesn't support variable length lookbehinds so you will need to type out the full pattern before, eg:

```
something test string: ABC:DEF
```

`ABC:DEF` Can be extracted with:

```
(?<=test string: )\w+(\.\w+)+
```

But not

```
(?<=test string)\w+(\.\w+)+
```

Comment: `grep -oE '\w+(\.\w+)+' data` is not safe because there may be `XX.YY` in the reason text. `grep -oP '(?<=...` works perfect! It's OK to not save to multiple files at one time. I can extract one type by one type. There are duplicates in the results, but I know how to deal with it, `grep ... | sort | uniq`. Thanks for this good A, especially the explanations on the options and regex.  @shellter I thought you'll make an answer but it seems you are an inspector on SO? :-P

Comment: @Lee FYI most versions of `sort` have `sort -u` to sort and uniq in one process.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thx.